# How to compute saddle point index using sourcing flow lines?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology, partial-derivative, multilinear-algebra

Prove $Index_{p}(\bigtriangledown f)$= "dimension of sourcing flow lines from p" ,where p is a critical point.

Attempt

Near $ p \in Cr(f) $ in some coord.
$ f(x) - f(p) = $ $\sum_j x_j^2 - \sum_k x_k^2\ $. Then by choosing a Riemannian
metric on
$ M $ coinciding with the standard Euclidean near $ p \in Cr(f) $
the gradient flow splits orbits near $ Cr(f) $ into stable $S_p$ and unstable
$US_p\ $, i.e. running into $ p \in Cr(f) $ as $t \to -\infty $ or, repectively
as $t \to +\infty\ $. Then $S_p$ and $US_p\ $ are manifolds near $p $ and
$T_p S_p$ and $T_p US_p$ are the linear subspaces of negative and, respectively,
positive eigenvalues of $ Hess_p(f)\ $.

Comment: Your proof looks about as simple as I can imagine.... :)

Comment: oh come on. I need one I can explain to undergraduates with second year calculus and differential equations background. Even an informal one will do.

Comment: If you're only looking for heuristics, then $\nabla f = 2\operatorname{diag}(x_1,\dots, x_{n-k}, -x_{n-k+1}, \dots, x_n)$ obviously repels the first $(n-k)$ coordinates and attracts the last $k$; you can even explicitly solve the flow equations. Perhaps that's more what you're looking for? Best wishes in any case.

Comment: why does it equal this diagonal? thanks

Comment: Just thinking of the Euclidean setting, in which $\nabla f$ is the vector of partials of $f$ and the gradient flow is a fully decoupled system. Incidentally, a minus sign got left off the last coordinate in my previous comment; assuming $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n-k} x_i^2 - \sum_{i=n-k+1}^n x_i^2$ (so $f$ has a non-degenerate critical point of index $k$ at the origin), the gradient field is $\nabla f = 2\operatorname{diag}(x_1, \dots, x_{n-k}, -x_{n-k+1}, \dots, -x_n)$. The space $\mathbf{R}^{n-k}\times\{0\}$ is unstable, and $\{0\}\times\mathbf{R}^{k}$ is stable.